# Remove author and affiliation for blind review using \documentclass{APA}

Tags: formatting

I'm using \documentclass{APA} for submission to a journal that requires APA format.  The submission is doubleblind and so I need to blind the document.  The way I have done this is as follows

```
\fourauthors{.}{.}{.}{.}
\fouraffiliations{.}{.}{.}{.}
```

This works, but of course places dots in the title page.  I would just like to have the title page blank, but simply removing the commands doesn't work.  Advice greatly appreciated.  Thank you,

David

Comment: Have your tried to put spaces instead of dots? Possibly what a backslash before.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work if you put some invisible character or a space like

```
\fourauthors{\,}{\,}{\,}{\,}
\fouraffiliations{\,}{\,}{\,}{\,}
```

For a more general approach without altering your document, add this code to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
    \long\def\@author{\,}
    \long\def\@affil{\,}
    \long\def\@authorOne{\,}
    \long\def\@affilOne{\,}
    \long\def\@authorTwo{\,}        
    \long\def\@affilTwo{\,} 
    \long\def\twoauthors#1#2{}
    \long\def\twoaffiliations#1#2{}
    \long\def\threeauthors#1#2#3{}
    \long\def\threeaffiliations#1#2#3{}
    \long\def\fourauthors#1#2#3#4{} 
    \long\def\fouraffiliations#1#2#3#4{}
\makeatother
```

The entries of one, two, three and four authors and their affiliations  will be cancelled. The title page will not be affected in any other way.

Before the patch

[image: A]

After the patch

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[man]{apa}

%%%************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
    \long\def\@author{\,}
    \long\def\@affil{\,}
    \long\def\@authorOne{\,}
    \long\def\@affilOne{\,}
    \long\def\@authorTwo{\,}        
    \long\def\@affilTwo{\,} 
    \long\def\twoauthors#1#2{}
    \long\def\twoaffiliations#1#2{}
    \long\def\threeauthors#1#2#3{}
    \long\def\threeaffiliations#1#2#3{}
    \long\def\fourauthors#1#2#3#4{} 
    \long\def\fouraffiliations#1#2#3#4{}
\makeatother
%%%**************************************

\title{Example of an APA-style manuscript}

%\author{Myself Author1}
%\affiliation{My Department}

%
%\twoauthors{Myself Author1}{Author2}
%\twoaffiliations{My Department}{The other place2}
%
%\threeauthors{Myself Author1}{Author2}{ Author3}
%\threeaffiliations{My Department}{The other place2}{Department3}
%
\fourauthors{Myself Author1}{Author2}{ Author3}{Author4}
\fouraffiliations{My Department}{The other place2}{Department3}{The other place4} 

\abstract{This is an example of a minimal ``manuscript'' using the \LaTeX\ apa.cls document class to typeset manuscripts according to the Americal Psychological Association (APA) manual, fifth edition.}

\acknowledgements{Written at the request of the Prac\TeX\ journal editors.

Comments may be sent to the author at protopap@ilsp.gr.}

\shorttitle{APA style manuscript}
\rightheader{APA style manuscript}
\leftheader{A.\ Protopapas}

\begin{document}
\maketitle                            
Here goes the text of the article. Note that the content begins immediately after \texttt{maketitle} and there is no blank line between the title command and the article text. This first section of the article is typically the introduction and, according to APA style, should not bear a section heading.\footnote{That is, there is no ``Introduction'' section.} Subsequent sections, however, are titled according to the psychological conventions.

\section{Experiment 1} 
Manuscripts in APA style often contain descriptions of experiments.  The APA manual specifications for referring to experiments are to use a lowercase ``e'' when speaking generally, as in the previous phrase, but an uppercase ``E'' when mentioning a particular experiment (as in the following phrase), such as Experiment~1. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!